# Rspec controller test fails after using kaminari for pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pagination, kaminari

My controller tests using rspec fails while using kaminari for pagination.My Controller code & rspec test are as given below.

app/controllers/courses_controller.rb

```
def index
  @courses = Course.all.page(params[:page]).per(15)
  authorize! :read, @courses

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @courses }
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/courses_controller.rb

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all courses as @courses" do
    course = create(:course)
    get :index, { }
    expect(assigns(:courses)).to eq([course])
  end
end
```

OUTPUT:

```
Failures:

1) CoursesController GET index assigns all courses as @courses
   Failure/Error: get :index, { }
   ArgumentError:
     wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
   # ./app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:5:in `index'
   # ./spec/controllers/courses_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

However if I do not use the pagination in controller it works, below is the code that dont use pagination.

```
def index
  @courses = Course.all
  authorize! :read, @courses

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @courses }
  end
end
```

Can you help to handle this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you try `get :index, :page => 1`..

Comment: I had already tried that... no help

Comment: @ArupRakshit thank you for your help.. the below reply solved the issue.

Comment: `Kaminari.paginate_array(Course.all).page(params[:page]).per(15)` try this and let me know. `Course.all` gives you array, so this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove `all` from the following line:

```
@courses = Course.all.page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

So it looks like this:

```
@courses = Course.page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

This seems to be more in line with the [Kaminari documentation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#query-basics):

```
To fetch the 7th page of users (default per_page is 25)

  User.page(7)

To show a lot more users per each page (change the per_page value)

  User.page(7).per(50)
```

Comment: Hwy i m surprised that this worked... I tried passing :page => 1 and other stuff.. However I never suspected that this could solve the problem.

Comment: Thank You... I spent a lot of time before I decided to post the question here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What @dax mentioned above solved my problem in one of the controller where I was selecting all courses however in another controller where I used nested resources this did not work. I followed @ArupRakshit comments and it works for all scenario.

Below is the fix for the problem.

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(Course.all).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```